# Property of rational exponentiation of a real number

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on the following Exercise:

"Let $x, y >0$ be positive reals, and let $q, r$ be rationals. Then:

(a) $x^q$ is a positive real.

(b) $x^{q+r}=x^q x^r$, $(x^q)^r=x^{qr}$

(c) $x^{-q}=1/x^q$

(d) if $q>0$ then $x>y$ iff $x^q>y^q$

(e) if $x>1$ then $ x^q > x^r$ iff $q>r$.
     if $x<1$ then $x^q>x^r$ iff $q<r$."

I've managed to prove cases $(a)-(d)$ but I'm struggling with case $(e)$; I've tried to argue by contradiction but I haven't gotten very far. So, I would appreciate any hints about how to start/carry out its proof.

Note: if $x>0$ is a real number and $q$ a rational number, then $x^q:=(x^{1/b})^a$.

Comment: By b and c you can assume $r=0$. Writing $q=a/b$, you just need to prove that $x>1\iff x^a>1$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Using (b), you can transform it into "if $x > 1$ then $x^s > 1$ iff $s > 0$" (and similar for $x < 1$). That may be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(e)$,  since $q>r,\ q-r>0$ and $x>1$, so using $(d)$, $x^{q-r}>1$ and then post multiply both sides by $x^r$, to prove the first part. For the second part,note that $x<1\implies 1/x>1$ and then apply the result of the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer/Hint :
For (b)
$$a^{q+r}=a^{n/m+r/s}=a^{\frac{sn+rm}{ms}}=(a^{sn+rm})^{1/ms}=(a^{sn}a^{rm})^{1/ms}$$
Now $sn,rm$ and $ms$ are integers so
$$(a^{sn}a^{rm})^{1/ms}=(a^{sn})^{1/ms}(a^{rm})^{1/ms}=a^{\frac{sn}{sm}}a^{\frac{rm}{sm}}=a^{n/m}a^{r/s}=a^qa^r.$$

This technique should be enough for you to do (c).

(e)

$$x^q>x^r\iff x^{n/m}>x^{r/s}\iff x^{\frac{n}{m}-\frac{r}{s}}>1\iff x^{\frac{n}{m}-\frac{r}{s}}>1^{\frac{n}{m}-\frac{r}{s}}$$

but this is (d).